Shield termination techniques on military-style connectors
References such as PT06A-10-6S (see image bellow) are military-style connectors. I would like to connect my cable's foil and braid shielding to the chassis ground of my connector pannel via the PT06A connector. My cable includes a 1 or 2 MHz differential pair signal.

They usually disassemble in such a fashion:

To reduce electromagnetic radiations, I have been told by EMC engineers that the shielding of a cable should not be connected through the shield's drain wire and should instead be done by taping with copper tape the shield's braid homogeneously around the cable and attached directly in contact with the connector, such as in the image bellow on a D-SUB connector.

What is the best practice to connect the cable's shield to a PT06A connector? Are there conditions under which you can use the drain wire efficiently enough for EMC, instead of using the 360-degree shield termination technique described on the D-SUB connector shown above?

Hhhhm, a 360-degree shield termination requirement on a connector with a giant air gap...  Have your EMC engineer take another look at the PT06 connector.  Just saying...

We used to pass it via one of the pins, and then connect it to the chassis inside the receiving side. Not sure it was the best practice though, as we didn't have any dedicated EMC engineers...

@EugeneSh. We used to pass it via one of the pins, and then connect it to the chassis inside the receiving side Dedicated EMC engineers will tell you not to do this. But if your requirements aren't too strict, it might work.

Could you mention what EMC requirements you have? Is it a commercial, automotive or military product? There's "EMC" ("flip a coin and see if you pass, then you get a pretty paper to show your friends") and there is EMC (shoot at the DUT with every bit of energy the lab can squeeze out).

Hi Lundin, I am aiming for:  Electrical safety: IEC 61010, and EMC: IEC 61326 & IEC 61000. Immunity in industrial, and emissions in residential.

I guess I could remove the rubber cable grommet and place my shield and copper tape directly there, around the cable

@Tommy95 Okay that's relatively timid requirements then compared to military EMC. The back shell solution with heat shrink will probably be ok - as I wrote in some comment I've gotten away with that solution for military testing but at 50V/m immunity, basically the same levels as most automotive testing iirc. Standard requirements for industry is somewhere around 30V/m but in some cases (certain mobile machinery, airport usage etc) they could up the requirements all the way to 100V/m in which case I do not recommend using these connectors with shield.

@Tommy95 Feel free to poke me in the chat if you want to discuss this. The company I work for builds lots of cable assemblies for shielded PT06. Given that it is the right solution for your project to begin with, that is.

Thanks a lot Lundin. Could you please provide an example of a "heat shrink back shell" you suggest? Is this it? At the moment, I am unsure what it would look like exactly, despite a Google search.

As it happens, I have a bit of experience of EMC problems related to shielding of PT06 connectors specifically. Yes you should connect the shield to the metal body of the connector. The conductivity of the connector body is fine, it is how you connect the shield to it that matters. That in turn requires that you have a suitable PT06 family connector that supports this and also with "back shells" (the part towards the cable) that support this.
Amphenol may or may not be able to provide that, depending on whom at Amphenol you speak to. They may in turn deliver you a solution which works, or deliver you one which does not work... My conclusion after spending way too much time on investigating this is that PT06 does not support shielded cables in any reliable way, period.
If this is for something tough and nasty like MIL-STD-461 testing, my recommendation would be to not rely on shielded cables at all. Depending on what level of radiated susceptibility testing that is required, you may or may not get away with shielding. I've gotten away with shielded PT06 during RS103 50V/m testing, but beyond that towards 200V/m levels, you need a perfect shield connection. And that won't even happen with these while they are lying on your desk, let alone on the parts that are out in the real world in very harsh conditions.

You don't: PT06A-10-6S is an "unshielded" type.  Which, makes sense given all the painted surfaces.
Catalog / datasheet: https://amphenol-industrial.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/pt-series-12-070.pdf
Evidently you would need to order a "SQ" variant from that series, or other manufacturers' equivalents.  I don't see a lot of those on distributors, so they may not be widely used / available in this series, and you'd want to choose a different family to start with.
Last time I used a shielded circular metal connector, it was a Hirose brand something or other.  Included in the plug assembly/kit, was a bit of adhesive gauze/tape to apply between cable braid and plug shell.  Sensible.  Such an item doesn't show in your image, and again, the paint would get in the way, and there's probably nowhere to put the gauze either -- you'd have a hard time indeed turning that one into a shielded type.
Amphenol is a bit of a nightmare to navigate, anyway; Cannon, Hummel, etc. all similar in this respect, broad pick-and-choose catalogs of make-your-own parts using modular designs (this housing, that insert, those pins... etc.).  Basically, you can have any configuration under the sun ...as long as you don't mind paying for it, and waiting many months for the factory to tool up and run off some parts... and MOQ probably, and so on and so on.  But this is de rigeur for circular connector families.  They're big, they're pricey, they're good at what they do... and, for every specialized application, every customer that's willing to pay for them, also has their own idea of what they want in one.  Hence the customizability.
Working through an FAE (field applications engineer) or other sales channel will likely prove most useful.

"given all the painted surfaces"  I think most often the surface is a chromate plating, which I think is conductive.  Sometimes you do see black-colored versions that are probably not conductive.  For those that really want to connect a shield, the most common hack I see is a ring terminal to one of the strain relief screws.  That extra effort must make someone feel better...

Is there an advantage to the ring terminal solution over using the drain wire to a pin of the connector?

Tim, the budget is on the very low end for this project, unfortunately. The connector is conductive at its surface, tested using a multimeter.

SQ is probably going to be a non-starter. Either by dint of MOQ, cost, lead time, or just plain old availability. Either get a heat shrink back shell and use a hideously expensive braid-lined heat shrink boot, try to find a twinax contact, or change connector families.

"Is there an advantage to the ring terminal solution over using the drain wire to a pin of the connector?"  Probably a question all in itself...  It all comes down to what you're trying to accomplish, and what signal type you're trying to effectively shield.  At 1 to 2 MHz, (with reasonable risetimes), you can do nearly anything at this scale to preserve shield *continuity *.  A ring terminal looks like one has attempted something, and probably works just as good as using a pin, especially when no spare pins are available.

Ah yes, that jogs a memory -- I have seen these terminated with the drain wire or braid to a lug on the strain relief. It does cost the uncoupled length though. Whether this matters, depends on the application.

@ChrisKnudsen Yes these are not painted, they conduct very well in fact, down towards 0 ohm. They do contain various unhealthy metals like cadmium though. Not RoHS conforming. And most military applications at least in EU is moving away from these for that reason. Black-colored might be zinc/nickel which do conform to RoHS.

@Tommy95 "the budget is on the very low end for this project, unfortunately" Then you should forget all about shielded cables. They cost around 10 to 100 times more than unshielded equivalents.

@vir We used heat shrink back shells with these, but Amphenol can't give you a straight answer if that's appropriate for PT06 or not. Formally I guess it is not. I would not recommended it either. I would not recommend shielded cables in general.

As the other answers say, it might not be possible to terminate the cable shield to the connector metal shell.
While it might be "the best" method according to EMC experts, you always don't need the most best and expensive solution, as sometimes a good enough solution will do just fine.
To put in in other words, if your device does not pass EMC testing unless you use the most expensive connectors, cables, and shielding termination methods, it might be simpler, cheaper and faster in the long run to redesign the device so that it does not need the most expensive connectors, cables and shielding termination methods to begin with.
Many interfaces with use plug connectors with a metal shell do not actually connect the cable shield to connector metal shell. The plug connector shell is just connected to nothing else than to the device chassis through the receptale, to act as an extension to the enclosure that surrounds the connections inside the plug metal shell.
The cable shield will then connect to just ordinary pins in the connector, like how many interfaces with XLR, D-Subminiature, or DIN connectors do.
It is also safer that way, as when you grab the plug connector, you know that the metal shell is unconnected and floating, so it is safe to touch and you don't get an electric shock if something has gone wrong in the other device or in the cable, unless you touch the pins inside the connector.

I'm not trying to be too irritating, but "safer... unconnected and floating, so it is safe to touch... if something has gone wrong".  Um, no.  All exposed metal parts in a electrical system should be earthed, if you're concerned about electrical safety.  Especially the conductive metal parts that are designed to be handled, unless you get into double-insulated or battery powered (power-limited) devices territory.

@ChrisKnudsen Ok, try telling that to people who set up gear at concerts and venues. There is a safety reason why even standard XLR audio cables have the cable plug metal shell disconnected. If the metal shells were connected together through the cable, it would mean that any fault or damage to cable or the plug on the other end that might make it live with mains would also make both metal shells live too. So, the metal shells of XLR connectors have no connection to the cable, it is only earthed by connecting to receptacle of local device.

Yeah, double insulated is fine. Any exposed metal parts on equipment will get tested for ESD for example; as, sometimes a strike to floating metal causes other nearby things to malfunction, even if a spark didn't jump from said metal part to internal things. It can be better to ground them to sink ESD rather than leave it floating, but it's not at all required to do so.

@Justme  I have heard that about the audio world (ouch, pun).  However, it's my suspicion that much of their habits are the living embodiment of a self-perpetuating XY problem.  It's a known fact that the most common cause of death for a band's drummer is electrocution, just after spontaneous combustion.
